# Outbound VPN connection from DMZ, without using jumpserver

Tags: cisco-asa, vpn

Im using a Cisco Asa 5505 but I don't think it has anything to do with the my issue.

I have 2 VLAN:s on my ASA Inside(192.168.1.) and DMZ(10.10.0.). In my DMZ I have one host that is used as a PPTP/VPN client, its basically connected to a VPN 24/7.

The issue im having is that I can't connect directly from the **inside** network to the host while it is connected to a VPN connection? (if the host is not connected to VPN it works)

Right now I use a jumpserver that resides in the DMZ zone, this works and I can connect from inside->jumpserver->VPN client server, while it's connected to a vpn connection.

But I want to be able to connect to the host while its connected to VPN without using the jumpserver first.

Is this possible? if so how?

And why can only hosts that resides on the same subnet connect to the host while it's connected to VPN?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because the vpn client routes everything except the local subnet, over the tunnel. To solve this you either need to configure the vpn head end to do split tunneling, or configure the asa to do NAT from inside to dmz.